# Examining the HTTP request Content-type header

Tags: http, http-headers

I need to do a spot of server-side parsing of raw HTTP headers - in particular the Content-type header.  Whilst what I see for this header in different browser is appears to confirm to the same rules of capitalization and space usage I need to be sure.  For the mainstream browsers is it safe to assume that this header string will bear the form (for multipart form data)

```
Content-type:...; boundary=...
```

or is it necessary to check for redundant spaces, e.g. `boundary =` etc?

Comment: Can you parse the source for say, Apache, and learn the vast majority of what you need to know?

Comment: @KevinDTimm  Done it - for all the mainstream browsers I have on my PC and it seems to be standard.  However, working to an assumption based on a spot of empirical observation is risky.

Comment: Not the logs but the source - if apache considers a method good enough I'm pretty sure I'd be happy with that too :)